# tabs and nav bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nav

I just created a menu with bootstrap.
When you are on the menu 4, I would like that when I put my cursor on the link 4, a horizontal sub-menu appears 4.

For this I tried to use the tabs class but it does not work!

Here is my code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/titi72/fzQUj/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stackrahul/fzQUj/2/

Comment: No that's what I want http://img191.imageshack.us/img191/1432/gtjw.png